# What is the main difference between the "return function" and the "callback function"?

Tags: swift, function, callback, closures

I think I am going to change all of my code functions from "callback functions" to "return functions". I don't like the "stairs" look of my code.

Do you think it is a good idea?

I don't understand the difference between the two (except for the asynchronous web service calls that force the use of the callback function in my code).

**Callback function:**

*Declaration:*

```
func methodToSelectData(strQuery : String, dataBase: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    let arryToReturn : [AnyObject] = []

    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: String(methodToCreateDatabase(dataBase: dataBase)!.absoluteString) )

    if (contactDB?.open())! {
        let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB?.executeQuery(strQuery, withArgumentsIn: nil)

        while results?.next() == true {
            arryToReturn.add(results!.resultDictionary())
        }

        if arryToReturn.count == 0 {
            completion(arryToReturn)
        }

        contactDB?.close()
    } else {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: contactDB?.lastErrorMessage()))")
    }
    completion(arryToReturn)
}
```

*Usage:*

```
DBHandler.sharedInstance.methodToSelectData(strQuery:"SELECT * FROM table", dataBase: "DB.db", completion: { resultQuery in
    if (resultQuery.count > 0) {
        ...
    }
})
```

**Return function**

*Declaration:*

```
func method2ToSelectData(strQuery : String, dataBase: String) -> [AnyObject] {
    let arryToReturn : [AnyObject] = []

    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: String(methodToCreateDatabase(dataBase: dataBase)!.absoluteString) )

    if (contactDB?.open())! {
        let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB?.executeQuery(strQuery, withArgumentsIn: nil)

        while results?.next() == true {
            arryToReturn.add(results!.resultDictionary())
        }

        if arryToReturn.count == 0 {
            return arryToReturn
        }

        contactDB?.close()
    } else {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: contactDB?.lastErrorMessage()))")
    }

    return arryToReturn
}
```

*Usage:*

```
let resultQuery =  DBHandler.sharedInstance.method2ToSelectData(strQuery:"SELECT * FROM table", dataBase: "DB.db")

if (resultQuery.count > 0) {
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to use one or the other? I don't understand the subtlety very well.

Comment: Don't use `NS*` classes in `Swift`

Comment: It was just for the example, I update it

Comment: Simple rule: If the method contains an asynchronous task use a *callback* otherwise *return* the data

Answer (score 0):

**It's really a matter of what you need in any given situation.**

For something as simple as returning a piece of data, you can do just that:

```
// Definition //
func newString(firstHalf: String, secondHalf: String) -> String {
    return firstHalf + secondHalf
}

// Usage //
print(newString(firstHalf: "Hello", secondHalf: "world"))
```

Something more complicated, like a data call, might need a completion handler or closure:

```
// Definition //
func getData(fromEndpoint endpoint: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
    let data = serverData(from: endpoint) //Makes the server request.
    completion(data)
}

// Usage //
getData(fromEndpoint: "https://www.reddit.com/.json") { data in
    doThings(with: data)
}
```

You don't necessarily *need* an asynchronous call to use a closure/callback, but it tends to be one of the most common use-cases for one. As you do more coding in Swift, you'll find more use-cases for each.

Comment: @ ZGski I understand for all the url connection etc... And what do you think about queries to the database?

Comment: @ΩlostA It depends on what you're doing exactly. I'm inclined to suggest the closure/callback since "queries to the database" might suggest an async or synchronous call. It's hard to tell exactly what you need without more specifics.